# what is the "largest" abelian subgroup of SL(2,Z)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I suppose "largest" is a bit of a nebulous term, so to make it precisely, I suppose I could ask for the largest size of a minimal generating set of an abelian subgroup's image in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

My intuition tells me that all abelian subgroups have the form:

1. Trivial, or
2. cyclic (infinite or order 2,3,4, or 6)
3. either of the above "direct producted" by $\{\pm1\}$

So, my conjectured minimal generating set of an abelian subgroup's image in PSL(2,Z) is...1

Is this correct?

Comment: ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is well-known to be isomorphic to the free product $C_2*C_3$, so its largest abelian subgroup has order $3$, and the largest of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is cyclic of order $6$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I never said every one of 1,2,3 was possible!

Comment: @DerekHolt well it can also have infinite cyclic (hence abelian) subgroups...

Comment: OK, but the way 3)  is written suggested (to me at least) that you thought all occurred. It also isn't clear whether you are asking about ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}).$